# how to install hypre using terminal on OS X 10.9.1

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I want to install the lastest version of Hypre. It must be safe So using terminal is the safest way. I have brew.

My question is : How can I do this using the terminal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand why you say it's safer to install it from the terminal. It's (almost) the same when you install it from the GUI.

Since the [official website](http://computation.llnl.gov/casc/hypre/software.html) uses a [form with a CGI](http://computation.llnl.gov/casc/hypre/download/hypre-2.9.0b_reg.html), you'll have to download the installer from your browser.

Comment: Yes I installed and unpacked it already but the problem is when I follow the instructions it says on terminal type ./configure but nothing happens . That is the problem.

Comment: I searched on the net and sites I have read are saying hypre is not provided for mac.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `brew tab homebrew-science` and then `brew install hypre`?

Comment: Hypre is not available in any default tap. Could you add the tap that includes hypre?

Comment: @grgarside you are wrong. `$ brew search hypre` results `homebrew/science/hypre`

Comment: @jherran That's exactly what I tried, [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2RYHL.png)